# Cannot launch rails app: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. deadlock; recursive locking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I'm trying to launch my rails app on VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04, but for some reason every time I use any rails or gem command like `rails s` or `bundle install` I get the following error message:

```
/home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    deadlock; recursive locking

Gem files will remain installed in /home/jakup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/jakup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/gem_make.out


Gem files will remain installed in /home/jakup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/jakup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /home/jakup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/psych-2.0.17/lib/psych.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:601:in `load_yaml'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:327:in `load_file'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:196:in `initialize'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `new'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `configuration'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:63:in `run'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:37:in `block in build'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tempfile.rb:319:in `open'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `block in require'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `each'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `find'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
    from /home/jakup/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /home/jakup/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I used to have this error in the past when I set my network adapter to bridged network on VirtualBox, but now this error occurs even when I'm not on bridged network, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a (temporary?) solution..

I was running the project from a shared folder between windows (host) and ubuntu (guest in virtualbox) for some reason when I run the project locally, so not within the shared folder and I unmount the folder, it works.

Don't ask me the details of why it works, it just magically does for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I will write in a form of a answer just to easier write.

Thy to delete all previously installed gems (e.g. delete the gems manually) and try to re-install them. It should be working then.

Don't delete these (ignore the versions of the gems):

```
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
bundler (1.11.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
```

Also, try to install gems inside `.bundle` directory not in a global namespace. Install it at first like `bundle install --path .bundle`, and I think every next time it will be using that directory

Comment: so manually delete all these folders? https://i.imgur.com/6U9J7q8.png and then run `bundle install --path .bundle` + I don't see any folder named .bundle, where is it located at?

Comment: hm, I think it should be safe, although, if there is a `bundle` gem there as well, don't delete it. There are number of the gems that are needed for the bundler to function - don't delete them. With bundle install path you will "vendor" your gems, which makes is much more easier to have separate gems for each project, and much easier to solve these kinds of issues. The folder will be created automatically in your project's directory. (the directory where you are running your `bundle install`)